# How do I set mp3s as ringtones on ICS?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ringtone

I just upgraded my Nexus-S to Ice Cream Sandwich, I can't find the option to set mp3s as ringtones for my contacts? what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the contact you want to add the ringtone to, press the menu button in the top right corner and select `Set ringtone`. The mp3 file has to be in the `/sdcard/Ringtones/` directory for the phone to find it.